# How to convert GMT to IST in iPhone programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am working on a project, in which I want to set an alarm in IST time, but I am getting GMT value.
I don't know what's the time differences and don't know how to convert GMT time to IST.

How to do this conversion?

Comment: its   +5:30 hrs difference between gmt and ist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // about date(IST)
> NSDateFormatter *istDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
> istDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"];
> istDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";;
> NSString *outDateStr = [istDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
> ```

Answer (score 1):

--userdefined function to get current indian time
ALTER FUNCTION [purpledbadmin].[GetIndianTime] ()
RETURNS DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    declare @IndianTime DateTime

```
set @IndianTime= GETDATE()+ convert(datetime, '05:30:00:000');

return @IndianTime
```

end